# Trying to read serial port data using PySerial code below and getting unwanted symbols/characters

Tags: python, serial-port, pyserial

With code below i'm getting unwanted symbols/characters.  As an example, in this case I should be only receiving "boot.last" but instead i'm getting "[0;0mboot.last [0m"

```
ser = serial.Serial(
port='COM1',
baudrate=9600,
parity=serial.PARITY_NONE,
stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
bytesize=serial.EIGHTBITS
```

)

```
ser.isOpen()

print ('Enter your commands below.\r\nInsert "exit" to leave the application.')

userin=1
while 1 :
    # get keyboard input
    userin = input(">> ")
        # Python 3 users
        # input = input(">> ")
    if userin == 'exit':
        ser.close()
        exit()
    else:
        # send the character to the device
        # (note that I happend a \r\n carriage return and line feed to the characters - this is requested by my device)
        ser.write(userin.encode('utf-8') + '\r\n'.encode('utf-8'))
        out = ''
        # let's wait one second before reading output (let's give device time to answer)
        time.sleep(1)
        while ser.inWaiting() > 0:
            out += ser.read(1).decode('ascii')

        if out != '':
            
            print(">>" + out)
```

Comment: Those look like ANSI escape sequences used perhaps to position the cursor https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_sequences . What’s the code at the sending end? What input do you put at this end to get this response? For example ESC [ 0 m is a SGR sequence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#SGR

Comment: Thanks.  I'm looking into what's going on with the sending end.